# Как перехватить прокрутку в сторону ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

У меня есть `ViewPager` с тремя `View`. Мне нужно перехватить прокрутку в сторону (имеет значение в какую). Какие для этого есть слушатели (поискал в интернете, но нужного мне не нашел)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределяй метод `onPageScrolled`, в котором с помощью параметров `position` и `offset` ты сможешь определить какой из трех фрагментов сейчас используется, и в какую сторону прокручивается. Или как вариант используй слушатель `onPageChangeListener`

Comment: Как именно я могу это сделать?

Comment: Достаточно непросто объяснить, советую переопределить, и глянуть отладчиком как эти параметры себя ведут. Offset ведет себя бешено, изменятся много раз в процессе одной прокрутки

Comment: А если пользователь начал прокрутку и не закончил? Мне нужно узнать закончил ли пользователь прокрутку, если да — в какую сторону или какой элемент там стоит в данный момент.

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPageScrolled(int position, float offset, int offsetPixels) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, offset, offsetPixels);
        Log.i("testscroll", "position "+position+", offset "+offset);
        
    }

Comment: Да, можно, разберись как ведут себя параметры, и опиши логику

Comment: Я знаю, как определить в какую сторону идет прокрутка (от начальной до конечной точки движения пальцем), но как узнать что прокрутка завершилась (встала другая страница)?

Comment: насколько я помню когда offset стала равной нулю

Comment: Стоп! Так offset станет равный нулю через определенное время (секунда две), а параметры функции мне придут сразу после начала прокрутки, то есть я не смогу понять, что страница уже встала.

Comment: ну тогда как вариант еще советую попробовать слушатель OnPageChangeListener

Comment: О! Это то, что нужно! Добавьте вариант про `onPageChangeListener` в ответ и я приму.

Comment: @bukashka101 Готово )